# C#: Natural Log needed with decimal values for financial purpose

Tags: c#, precision, finance, natural-logarithm

Is there a way to compute a natural log using decimal values in C#?
I need something like

```
decimal dec = Math.Log(decimalInput);`
```

The problem is that `Math.Log(x)` only works with a double type as input and another double as output.

Comment: Convert decimal to double...?

Comment: `var dec = (decimal)Math.Log((double)decimalInput);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that's a bad idea. it loses precision.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, it loses precision but I'm not following why it is necessarily a bad idea. Under what circumstances is 15 decimal digits of precision insufficient for a *log* operation?

Comment: Precision is required as it is used in a financial correlation analysis that involves a lot of natural log applied on a lot of decimal values